# Find $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2+5x+6}$ using residues.

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

> Find $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}\ dx}{x^2+5x+6}$$

This problem is slightly unusual as the poles are on the real axis, + it has the square root so we will need to deal with a log branch.

Here a terrible sketch of my contour.
[image]

I know that the integral over $z_2$ and $z_4$ goes to $0$ regardless of how much of an arch we make. $z_1$ gives us the desired integral letting $\epsilon \to 0$. Now $z_3$ is parameterized so that it is a straight line a little bit below the real axis $z_3(t)=t+i\delta, t\in [-\sqrt{R^2-\delta^2},-\sqrt{\epsilon^2-\delta^2}]$. Now by definition of contour integral over $z_3$ we get $$\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-\delta^2}}^{-\sqrt{\epsilon^2-\delta^2}}\frac{\sqrt{t+i\delta}}{(t+i\delta)^2+5(t+i\delta)+6}$$ letting $\delta \to 0$ ( I am having trouble justifying moving the limit inside) we get $\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\sqrt{t}}{t^2+5t+6}$ which is imaginary, so we just have to take the real part of the residue and we are done.

Is this correct? It gives me the right answer but i am not sure if all i did was valid.

Comment: Sorry, where is the sketch? What are $z_{1,2,3,4}$?

Comment: @Andrei Very sorry, not sure what happened.

Comment: Since the poles are on the axis I think you can half their residue when summing.

Comment: The integral $\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon} \sqrt x/(x^2 + 5 x + 6) dx$ diverges. You can show that your original integral is equal to
$$\frac 1 2 \left( \int_{i0}^{\infty + i0} f(x) dx -
 \int_{-i0}^{\infty - i0} f(x) dx \right) =
\pi i \left( \operatorname* {Res}_{x = -2} f(x) +
 \operatorname* {Res}_{x = -3} f(x) \right),$$
with the square root in $f(x)$ chosen to be analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus [0, \infty)$ with the positive limit from above on $(0, \infty)$.

Comment: @Maxi you are indeed correct! Could you tell me how you arrived at this? IS this Indentation lemma?

Comment: Example 4 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_4_%E2%80%93_branch_cuts) is almost exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do $x=y^2$ and $\mathrm dx=2y\,\mathrm dy$, then your integral becomes$$2\int_0^\infty\frac{y^2}{y^4+5y^2+6}\,\mathrm dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{y^2}{y^4+5y^2+6}\,\mathrm dy.$$Now, you are integrating a function which has poles at $\pm\sqrt2\,i$ and $\pm\sqrt3\,i$. So, your integral is equal to$$2\pi i\left(\operatorname{res}\left(\sqrt 2\,i,\frac{z^2}{z^4+5z^2+6}\right)+\operatorname{res}\left(\sqrt 3\,i,\frac{z^2}{z^4+5z^2+6}\right)\right).$$These residues are equal to $\frac{\sqrt2}2i$ and to $-\frac{\sqrt3}2i$ respectively. So, your integral is equal to $\pi\left(\sqrt3-\sqrt2\right)$.

Comment: Thank you. I did not even think of doing a $u$-sub, I always assumed these problems came with the simplest form. Now this makes me wonder, will this always "work" when we have a square root. One trouble with $\sqrt()$ is that you need to deal with log branches, but this sub would seem to eliminate that problem always. Thought perhaps after that substitution the rational function is messy but the point still stands that no more branch problem.

Comment: Note that an important feature of the function that you were integrating was that, after the substitution, it became an even function. Thanks to that, I was able to turn the problem of computing an integral from $0$ to $\infty$ into a problem of computing an integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. So, if it gives you an even function, then, yes, it will work.